# OOP PHP: Using parent's static element in declaration of child static element?

Tags: php, class, static

I'm trying to write a class that uses its parent's static declared array to add a new value to. Below is kind of a feel of how I'm trying to run it...

```
class SuperClass
{

protected static $array_name = array('value1');

}

class SubClass extends SuperClass 
{

protected static $array_name = array_push(parent::$array_name, 'value2');

}
```

Is there any way to properly implement this without a __construct() function?

I'm trying to implement a static working model for the SuperClass and its parents...

Comment: Short answer is: No, you cannot since you can't have logic code outside of function bodies in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if you want static classes completely, but this does what you want give or take :

```
<?php
class SuperClass
{
    static $array_name = array('value1');
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{

    static $array_name = 'foo';
    function __construct(){

        self::$array_name = array_push(parent::$array_name, 'value2');
    }
}
$foo = new SubClass();
var_dump($foo::$array_name);  // prints INT 2 - as push returns number of elements in array.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up implementing this in a different way. I'm actually creating a new instance of the object from a SuperSuperClass... Had to reconfigure a few things, but this ended up working.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped, Feel free to approve the answer if it really did help you, if not, no worries :)